# point rendering in openGL and GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

Question: How do I render points in openGL using GLSL?

---

Info: a while back I made a gravity simulation in python and used blender to do the rendering. It looked something like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dChaOM7pUJM). As an exercise I'm porting it over to openGL and openCL. I actually already have it working in openCL, I think. It wasn't until i spent a fair bit of time working in openCL that I realized that it is hard to know if this is right without being able to see the result. So I started playing around with openGL. I followed the openGL GLSL tutorial on wikibooks, very informative, but it didn't cover points or particles.

I'm at a loss for where to start. most tutorials I find are for the openGL default program. I want to do it using GLSL. I'm still very new to all this so forgive me my potential idiocy if the answer is right beneath my nose. What I'm looking for is how to make halos around the points that blend into each other. I have a rough idea on how to do this in the fragment shader, but so far as I'm aware I can only grab the pixels that are enclosed by polygons created by my points. I'm sure there is a way around this, it would be crazy for there not to be, but me in my newbishness is clueless. Can some one give me some direction here? thanks.

Comment: I'm not absoultely sure I understand your problem correctly. From what I understand you ask how to draw a halo around each of your points. There a typically to methods of doing that, either generate additional geometry (a quad centered on your point, can be generated by geometry shaders if available), which is textured as the halo or render without halos first and do posprocessing on the complete image in a second step (e.g. blur around the points). As long as you can live with standard blending operations I would suggest using the first options, by virtue of being easier and probably faster

Comment: right. I'm still new to this so these simple ideas hadn't occurred to me. I currently don't really know how post-processing works. I understand the concept, but I'm not really sure where to start with it. But the quad idea sounds simple and straight forward enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you want is to render the particles as `GL_POINTS` with `GL_POINT_SPRITE` enabled, then use your fragment shader to either map a texture in the usual way, or generate the halo gradient procedurally.

When you are rendering in `GL_POINTS` mode, set `gl_PointSize` in your vertex shader to set the size of the particle. The `vec2` variable `gl_PointCoord` will give you the coordinates of your fragment in the fragment shader.

EDIT: Setting `gl_PointSize` will only take effect if `GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE` has been enabled. Alternatively, just use `glPointSize` to set the same size for all points. Also, as of OpenGL 3.2 (core), the `GL_POINT_SPRITE` flag has been removed and is effectively always on.

Comment: could you perchance reference some examples. I'm only finding things that don't use GLSL. thanks.

Comment: I marked yours as the answer, even though it isn't quite working, but I think I'm on the right track now. Thanks.

Comment: Thing is, I couldn't really find any examples myself. What I know I got from the man pages playing around until it worked.

Comment: about where I am. at least now I know not to waste my time searching. xD thanks.

Answer (score 0):

simply draw a point sprites (using GL_POINT_SPRITE) use blending functions: gl_src_alpha and gl_one and then "halos" should be visible. Blending should be responsible for "halos" so look for some more info about that topic.
Also you have to disable depth wrties.

here is some link about that: [http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Tutorial_Framework:Particles](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL%3aTutorials%3aTutorial_Framework%3aParticles)